# Given an OracleDataReader, how do I return the entire resultset?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have the code below that currently returns a list of business objects. Although it works, I want to reduce the amount of repetitive code we have sitting around. Since the code below is type-specific - each BO has it's own ConnecToDbAndGetItems() method - this entire method gets duplicated for each BO.

```
con.Open();
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
BuildListOfItems(dr, ref itemsToReturn);
con.Close();
dr.Close();
```

I would prefer something like this, a small incremental change that's easy to manage:

```
con.Open();
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// Gimme all the data here and
// return that to another method for building BOs

con.Close();
dr.Close();
```

The end result is a generic data retrieval mechanism that all GetXXX() methods can call and the results (array, list, ???) are passed to a builder object for further processing.

How can I get all the records from the reader?

Comment: Checkout the OracleDataAdapter -- can fill a DataTable with all results. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataTable like that:

```
DataTable result = new DataTable();
result.Load(dr);
```

We used both DataAdapter and DataReader in our project. I can say that, DataReader provides better performance. You should set FetchSize property for better performance.